# Find button's Xpath in webapps [Selenium]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to browse this page:

https://webapps.cityofchicago.org/activegcWeb/

But I can't find how move to any page, with chrome I get this Xpath for the 'next' button:

```
'//*[@id="id2"]/a[3]'
```

I'm using this code:

```
url = 'https://webapps.cityofchicago.org/activegcWeb/'
driver_1 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver_1.get(url)
content = driver_1.page_source

next_button_xpath = '//*[@id="id2"]/a[3]' 
button = driver_1.find_element_by_xpath(next_button_xpath)
button.click()
```

But I got this error:

```
'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=\"id2\"]/a[3]"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just find the next button *by the link text*:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text(">").click()
```

Complete working code (including the window maximizing and the wait):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = 'https://webapps.cityofchicago.org/activegcWeb/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

# click next
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, ">"))).click()
```

Comment: I got this:  Error Message => 'Unable to find element with link text '>''

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez updated the answer, works for me, please check.

Answer (score 1):

With XPath locator "//a[contains(@href, 'headerPaginator:next')]" and then just click.

Comment: I got this: Error Message => 'Unable to find element with xpath '//a[contains(@href, 'headerPaginator:next')]''